# Change format of date column in CSV

Tags: python, windows, perl, csv

I have CSV file with the following format

```
Column_a,Column_b,Column_c,Column_date
a,b,c,08-jun-2017 00:00 to UP (ENG)
```

I want to convert the data with name `Column_date`

Example: `08-jun-2017 00:00 to UP (ENG)` should be converted to `17W23D4 to UP (ENG)`

The format is year within century `17`; week of year `W23`; day of week `D4`. The days go from Monday (1) to Sunday (7).

So the final CSV should look like:

```
Column_a,Column_b,Column_c,Column_date
a,b,c,17W23D4 to UP (ENG)
```

It would be great if can do in a `.bat` file, but another scripting language is also okay.

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm/logic to map `08-jun-2017 00:00 to UP (ENG)` to `17W23D4 to UP (ENG)`.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: basically 08-jun-2017 00:00 should be changed to 23rd week and day 4 (Monday is 1st day of week) of year 2017

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, you can use [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece):

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -wE '
    $tp = Time::Piece->strptime("08-jun-2017 00:00", "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M");
    say $tp->yy, "W", $tp->week, "D", $tp->day_of_week'
17W23D4
```

You first need to extract the date and time from the string, though.

You can use `-F,` to split each line on commas into the @F array, then use a regex to extract the timestamp:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F, -anE '
    print, next if $. == 1;
    ($timestring, $rest)
        = pop(@F) =~ /([0-9]{2}-[a-z]{3}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(.*)/;
    $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($timestring, "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M");
    say join ",", @F, $tp->yy . "W" . $tp->week . "D" . $tp->day_of_week . $rest;
' -- input.csv
```

IIRC, on MSWin you need to switch single and double quotes.

See [pop](http://p3rl.org/pop), [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre), [join](http://p3rl.org/join) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

**I want to convert the data with name `Column_date`**

The following **Python** solution is based on [`datetime` — Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) documentation. Please scroll down to [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) section for meaning of `%y`, `%V`, `%u`, … directives:

```
^^> python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> ColDateOld = '08-jun-2017 00:00'   ### extract from `CSV`
>>> ColDateNew = datetime.strptime(ColDateOld, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M').strftime("%yW%VD%u")
>>> print( ColDateNew)                 ### populate the result
17W23D4
>>>
>>>
```

Read and follow [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html?highlight=csv) as well.